# Multiprocessing with python nothing happens

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use Multiprocessing to scrape web pages but when I launch my program, nothing happened so I tried the (very) simple example and also nothing happens. So the problem seems to be with multiprocessing :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Any ideas ?
I am on macbookPro with JupyterLab 2.2.6
Thx

Comment: This code does indeed work. Have you verified if `if __name__ == '__main__':` is being entered? I have no experience with `JupyterLab`, but the simplest explanation is it's running code in such a way that `__name__` isn't `'__main__'`.

Comment: yes maybe jupyterlab doesn't have `'__main__'` as `__name__` there

Comment: Probably you should use `Multithreading` instead of `Multiprocessing` as you are doing web scraping..which is I/O bound operation not CPU bound.

Comment: Ya, assuming they aren't doing any heavy processing of data within the pool, threads would be more appropriate here than using processes.